# How can I find a speaker to talk about the community workings of stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion, moderators, stackexchange.com

I am looking for a speaker located in Europe that would be willing to give a talk in NL/DE about the workings of these websites. Not from a technical POV, but from a community knowledge sharing perspective. How do these web sites work. What are the motivations to provide answers, etc.

I considered the "contact us" but this might be too restricted. I found the blog, but I'm not sure who is blogging here and I don't have a way to contact them in single email. It does not have to be someone from the company behind SE.

I think there is a lot of consideration about how to make these community web sites work. And probably there are people discussing about the reward mechanisms, etc. Is this meta site a good place? Is there a more specific site or tag?

The core information I'm looking for is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but we need someone which can explain it and shield questions, e.g., how did you come up with all those badges? Do they really work as a motivation factor to contribute questions or answers? What are the main motivations for people to reply to answers (it's not simply to get points)?

A somewhat related question is [How do I find moderators on this site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72398/how-do-i-find-moderators-on-this-site?rq=1)

Comment: You should really use the "contact us" link.

Comment: I used that link more than a week ago but got no reply.

Comment: @Koriander: consider adding contact info in your SE-profile (it may help to get replies, eg from me). As a variation, use my profile to contact me please. Dank bij voorbaat! (Oeps: thanks in advance!). PS: please add a comment around here, to confirm you saw my msg. That way I can delete this comment again (= trick nr 1 of 'the working of these website', since PM-messages seems to not be allowed ... and as suggested to me recently by another SE user ... Je moet het maar weten hé.)

Comment: Weird, I see no option to put info in my profile??

Comment: Koriander, go to your profile and find the 3 links upperleft, which are "Profile", "Activity" and "Edit profile and settings".The select "Edit profile and Settings. As a variation, view "my" profile, and then scroll down to find my contact link (near the bottom within that box with varous Drupal Module name)

Comment: nope, but I know what's the issue, it is an account created in stackoverflow. There I have my email but I don't know if you can access it. For you I only see a web site name.